# Scrapy installation fails

Tags: python, scrapy, pip, failed-installation

Below is the end of the log file with the error I receive when I try to install Scrapy. I am rather inexperienced so it may be obvious to one of you. My computer is **windows 8.1 64-bit**. I have looked at the msvccompliler.px and there is no apparent indent error at the given line. I am pretty sure this stems from the `openssl` portion of the install. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 23, in <module>

from distutils.msvccompiler import get_build_version

File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvccompiler.py", line 159

return 9.0

^

IndentationError: unexpected indent

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rjudge\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging1218832657586108286.tmp\cryptography
Storing complete log in C:\Users\rjudge\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: 9+ years later: I have Python 2.7 installed specifically to test how things used to work in Python 2.7... I can't find anything like the code from the traceback in the corresponding standard library source file. It seems that someone must have edited it. It is extremely dubious that a floating point number would ever have been used to represent a version number in the Python standard library - there are many reasons why floating-point is completely unsuitable for the task.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a text editor for your code (ie. sublime text, notepad++, etc) try to open the script with the indent error and try to convert tabs to spaces.  Sometimes tabs mixed with spaces will cause "unexpected indent".

Comment: The error message clearly shows that the problem is inside a standard library file, which seems to have become corrupted somehow.